# Error while using jprofiler for profiling remote weblogic server

Tags: jprofiler

Hi I am new to jprofiler . My task is to profile a remote weblogic server for which i have followed the steps for remote profiling and came till sh file creation which the jprofiler creates itself. As i have read I need to start my weblogic server with this sh file .
But i am stuck up with the following error.

:Error occured during initialisation of VM could not find agent library in the absolute path ......./linuxX64/libjprofilerti.so

I can see the file in path mentioned in the error. Help needed quickly .

Thanks in advance,
Raghu dev

Answer (score 1):

Likely, you're profiling a 32-bit JVM, not a 64-bit JVM. Repeat the integration wizard and deselect the "64-bit JVM" check box on the "Profiled JVM" step. Then it should work.

Comment: i will describe the steps i have followed.in my local machine i have opted for remote profiling and performed all the steps.I had to mount the sh file of my weblogic server .since i didnot have a mount option i have copied the path of my weblogic's sh file to the local machine and generated _jprofiler.sh file . I have copied this sh file into the remote machine .when i am trying to start my weblogic server with this sh file i am getting this error.

Comment: Then the path to the native library in the -agentpath VM parameter in the modified start script is incorrect.

Comment: what should be the path to native library . native library means is that the path of jprofiler bin and one more question should i run my weblogic server with the sh file generated by jprofiler inorder to profile it

Comment: The path after the -agentpath must exist, it points to a native library in the JProfiler installation directory. Yes, you have to use the generated start script to load the profiling agent.

Comment: or else can i do the profiling this way . i will run the jpenable sh file in the remote machine select my weblogic server jvm select a port number then attach to the jprofiler GUI in the local machine with this port.

Comment: "-agentpath:/wls_domains/wlsdomain01/jprofiler7/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so path exists in the sh file created by jprofiler

Answer (score 0):

uncheck the 64-bit vm option in jprofiler while creating the profiling settings. this should solve the issue